# Can I say "they are of board" in this context?

Tags: word-usage

When I want to say that a piece of plywood is square or rectangular (board  /panel) and not long and narrow (strip / slat), can I say "they are of board"?

Or just say that they are boards, not strips?

Comment: A board could be long and narrow too (e.g. a floorboard). Simpler to just say that the piece is square.

Comment: It's chunky (fattish). 'Be of' is dated and reminds me of 'be of good cheer' or 'with child.'

Answer (score 1):

Although *some* dictionary definitions of "board" imply that it is a rectangular shape rather than a perfect square, either by using the word "rectangular" or "long", the word primarily describes the material (which could be any wood, timber, or even man-made fibres such as MDF), *not the shape*. On the other hand, the word "strip" means a "long and narrow" piece of almost any material, so this word is very much defining a shape, not a particular material or type of material. You cannot, therefore, assume that these two words are interchangeable.

Your suggested sentence "*they are of board*" does not sound idiomatic at all. Because "boards" can be made from a range of materials we would *not* say something is made "of board". However, we do tend to collectively call pre-cut boards "boarding", and if you cut a board into strips, for example, you could refer to them as "strips of boarding".

To describe pre-cut boards of wood I would simply say they are "boards", or "some boarding".

Answer (score 0):

"they are of board" sounds really alien, I advise you against using it.

I would say it simple:

> square / rectangular piece of plywood

If the material is not relevant, but only the purpose (e.g. some flat surface to write on), just use:

> board / blackboard / whiteboard

As an extra, **"board"** refers usually to a surface (thin flat "object"), rather than to a shape.